# Не правильно работает код на Pascal, который должен выводить минимальную четную цифру натурального числа, данного пользователем

Tags: алгоритм, математика, pascal

Например при вводе числа 555565 выводится 2, хотя должно выводиться 6.
Прошу предлагать решения данной проблемы только с использованием базового синтаксиса. Также хотелось бы добавить сообщение выводящееся при отсутствии четных цифр в числе.
Заранее благодарен.

```
    program xxx;
    var a, b,c, min :integer;
    begin
     write('введите число а='); 
     read(a);
     min:=10;
     while a<>0 do
      begin
       b:= a mod 10;
       c:= b mod 2;
       if (b < min) and (c=0) then min:=b;
       a:= a div 10;
      end;
     writeln(min)
    end.
```

Comment: Убедитесь, что у вас нет переполнения. Вы объявляете число a как integer, но вводите значение `555565`, которое может быть за пределами целого числа - просто моя догадка.

Answer (score 1):

Я проверил код на онлайн-компиляторе:
https://rextester.com/l/pascal_online_compiler

Он выдал 2

Если посмотреть, что хранится в переменной `a`, то оказывается, что там изначально вместо `555565` `31277`, отсюда и `2` в ответе

Если записать код так:

`var a, b,c, min :Int64;`

то все начинает работать правильно

С `Longint` тоже все правильно работает, в общем проблема в типе `integer`, используйте лучше платформонезависимый тип

Похоже у вас `integer` - это `Smallint`, а его для числа `555565` маловато :)

Comment: Большое вам спасибо

Comment: @DarkKnight, когда у вас какая-то фигня вместо ожидаемого результата идет, то помогает или отладка, когда вы пошагово идете по строчкам кода (ну не вы, а программа), и вы видите, что записывается в переменные. А если нет отладки (не знаю, какую среду разработки вы использовали), по можно просто в подозрительных местах натыкать вывод результата на экран - я просто натыкал в цикле writeln(a) и writeln(b) и увидел что именно происходит, поэтому быстро стало понятно в чем дело - единственное место где число может изменяться после ввода - это при преобразовании типа